# android project folder error in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]

The mark on my project folder..
How to solve it and why I got this error (!symbol on project folder)..
My project is not running saying as you have errors in your project please fix it message.
How can I overcome from this, and also tell how to connect MS SQLserver, I'm new in android
I tried to add jtsd jar file then i just refreshed my project, then i got this error.

Comment: Look in the 'Problems' view for messages about your project.

Comment: Right click project-properties-android select the target. May help you..

Comment: Check your project properties that every library required for your project are added properly.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on MY CABLE->Properties->Android
And check libraries
And you have to add jar libraries by this way:
Right Click on MY CABLE->Properties->Java Build Bath->Libraries->Add External JARs...

Answer (score 0):

Please check your res>layout>xml files. Also check your android.manifest file. Those items are not visible in your screenshot.

If those files don't show an error then your should check the library files. Check if it has been added right to your project.

The .java files in the screenshot seems to be okay.

Comment: i checked every xml files and manifest file too. there is no errors.did u saw that symbol on project folder.why it comes

Comment: Try to build the project. What error messages do you see?

Comment: Also change MY CABLE to MY_CABLE